# When I load a texture as RGBA4444 in openGL, how much memory is consumed in the device?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, textures

How much memory will consume a texture loaded with this method ?

With this method, will a 1024x1024 texture consume 4MB  anyway ? ( regardless of loading it as RGBA4444 ) ?

```
-(void)loadTexture:(NSString*)nombre {
CGImageRef textureImage     =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:nombre ofType:nil]].CGImage; 
if (textureImage == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to load texture image");
    return;
}


// Dimensiones de nuestra imagen
imageSizeX= CGImageGetWidth(textureImage);
imageSizeY= CGImageGetHeight(textureImage);

textureWidth = NextPowerOfTwo(imageSizeX);  
textureHeight = NextPowerOfTwo(imageSizeY);


GLubyte *textureData = (GLubyte *)calloc(1,textureWidth * textureHeight * 4);

CGContextRef textureContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(textureData, textureWidth,textureHeight,8, textureWidth * 4,CGImageGetColorSpace(textureImage),kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast );
CGContextDrawImage(textureContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (float)textureWidth, (float)textureHeight), textureImage);

/**************** Convert data to RGBA4444******************/   
//Convert "RRRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAA" to "RRRRGGGGBBBBAAAA"
void *tempData = malloc(textureWidth * textureHeight * 2);
unsigned int* inPixel32 = (unsigned int*)textureData;
unsigned short* outPixel16 = (unsigned short*)tempData;
for(int i = 0; i < textureWidth * textureHeight ; ++i, ++inPixel32)
    *outPixel16++ = 
    ((((*inPixel32 >> 0) & 0xFF) >> 4) << 12) | // R
    ((((*inPixel32 >> 8) & 0xFF) >> 4) << 8) | // G
    ((((*inPixel32 >> 16) & 0xFF) >> 4) << 4) | // B
    ((((*inPixel32 >> 24) & 0xFF) >> 4) << 0); // A


free(textureData);
textureData = tempData;

// Ya no necesitamos el bitmap, lo liberamos
CGContextRelease(textureContext);

glGenTextures(1, &textures[0]);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, textureWidth, textureHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4, textureData);

free(textureData);


//glEnable(GL_BLEND);

glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

}

Answer (score 3):

The [GL ES 1.1.12 specification (pdf)](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/1.1/es_full_spec_1.1.12.pdf) has this to say on the subject:

> The GL stores the resulting texture with internal component resolutions of its
>   own choosing. The allocation of internal component resolution may vary based
>   on any TexImage2D parameter (except target), but the allocation must not be a
>   function of any other state and cannot be changed once established.

However, according to the [iphone dev center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesForWorkingWithTextureData/TechniquesForWorkingWithTextureData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH104-SW1), RGBA4444 is natively supported. So I would expect it to consume 2MB with your code snippet. Do you have reasons to doubt it's using 2MB ?

Comment: I have doubts: Does the texture has mipmaps? Does the graphic chip needs alignment of the texture-scanlines (or blocks) in memory? If so, which alignment and how many bytes are wasted?

Comment: @Nils Pipenbrinck: Well, yes, the implementation may have some overhead. I may have read too much into the question, but it sounded like the author was wondering if the implementation would expand to RGBA8888. That, from the documentation, is not the case. As for mipmaps, well, it clearly loads only one level, and picks LINEAR filtering. I would be shocked if an embedded system would require the full mip-chain allocation when not in use. BTW, textures are generally tiled, not stored in scanlines. And... 1024 happens to fit most alignment reqs.

Comment: I know about an embedded graphic chip that can only start a texture or mipmap-level at an 8k boundary.. That blows up the memory requirements a lot.

Comment: @Nils Pipenbrinck: not 2MB, though. I'm curious now, which chip ?

Comment: My tests on the iPad have shown that RGBA4444 consumes as much memory as RGBA8888. I have compared memory usage accounted by my internal counter and Allocations Instrument. So RGBA4444 1024x1024 in my case consumes 4MB of memory and not 2MB as I expected ((

Answer (score 1):

In OpenGL, there is no way to find out how much video-memory a texture uses.

Also there is no single answer to the question to start with. Such details depend on graphic card, driver version, platform..

Comment: There is absolutely a way, which even beginners can try. This answer should be deleted, as it's not a real answer. Saying "No, there is no answer." is not a real answer. It's simply an incorrect statement that most of us call 'spam'. Flagged it as spam. Shame on the user who upvoted this. Especially when the above answer is a real answer. Just goes to show that this website is more about friends upvoting one another, not actually voting based on quality answer. This answer should have a multitude of downvotes.

Comment: @user15875 - This is not at all spam, it is a legitimate answer to the question asked. If you believe it to be wrong, vote it down, but flags are not to be used for technical issues with answers.

Answer (score 1):

From the [OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesForWorkingWithTextureData/TechniquesForWorkingWithTextureData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH104-SW1):

> If your application cannot use
>   compressed textures, consider using a
>   lower precision pixel format. A
>   texture in RGB565, RGBA5551, or
>   RGBA4444 format uses half the memory
>   of a texture in RGBA8888 format. Use
>   RGBA8888 only when your application
>   needs that level of quality.

Above that paragraph, they also really recommend using PVRTC compressed textures, because they save even more memory.

Comment: please suggest me for android also. i need to convert argb8888 to argb4444